# Calling multiple mpirun within Slurm job

Tags: python, subprocess, mpi, slurm

I am running a python script using Slurm that calls `subprocess.Popen("mpirun -np 14 ...")` twice in a row, on a system with 28 cores. So I expect that each call uses 14 cores, but only one of these calls seems to start (thus only using 14 cores). I have tried every possible combination of `--ntasks=28, --cpus-per-task=1`, `--ntasks=2, --cpus-per-task=14`, etc. in the batch script but nothing works.

Batch script:

```
#!/bin/bash
# Job name:
#SBATCH --job-name=job
#
# Account:
#SBATCH --account=acc
#
# Partition:
#SBATCH --partition=p
#
# Quality of Service:
#SBATCH --qos=q
#
#SBATCH --nodes=1
#
#SBATCH --ntasks=28
#
#SBATCH --time=08:00:00
#
#SBATCH --output=job_%j.out
#SBATCH --error=job_%j.err

## Command(s) to run:
python script.py
```

It works when simply running the script with python, without Slurm.

EDIT:

script.py:

```
from subprocess import Popen

p1 = Popen('mpirun -np 14 hostname'.split())
p2 = Popen('mpirun -np 14 hostname'.split())

p1.wait()
p2.wait()
```

It only prints 14 hostnames and the script never exits. When redirecting the output of each process to a file, only one process prints hostnames and the other one does nothing.

Comment: Please edit your question and add your (trimmed) submission script.

Comment: I am unable to reproduce the issue. can you please upload your `script.py` and specify the MPI library (vendor and version) you are using?

Comment: The result of `mpirun --version` gives Version 3.2.1, Release Date:                            Fri Nov 10 20:21:01 CST 2017